# "analysis of" vs. "analysis on"

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, sentence-construction, word-meaning

Which one is correct?

> We conduct an analysis on more than X devices

Or,

> We conduct an analysis of more than X devices

Comment: Take your pick. They mean essentially the same thing.

Comment: They mean different things. We need more context to give you an accurate answer.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

"We conduct an analysis *of* more than X devices" means that we are analysing devices, and we analyse many of them.

"We conduct an analysis *on* more than X devices" means that we are analysing *something*, and to do that analysis, we have repeated the same analysis of *something* using many devices.

So, without further context, my guess is:

**"Analysis of" is probably correct.**